# Extract "(more)" text with Selenium from Quora - Python

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scraping Quora answers.
Considering this link for example:
https://www.quora.com/Is-it-too-late-for-an-X-year-old-to-learn-how-to-program

Look the first answer, there is a "more" label witch indicates the presence of more text hidden.

**Problem**
Using Selenium in Python i can't open and extract text from this item.

**I try...**
I try also to click with the JavaScript to the link "Show more" with this istruction:

```
   try:
       if ans.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "more_link")]').is_displayed():
                    elem_more = ans.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "more_link")]')
                    #self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem_more )
                    Hover = webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(elem_more)
                    Hover.click(elem_more).perform()
                    #wait_1.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "switch_indicator")))
   except (NoSuchElementException,TimeoutException) as e:
       pass
```

And after take the content of the answer with

```
 content = ans.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[contains(@class, "inline_editor_value")]')
```

This works with an answer witout "More" becouse is the same container that I use to extract text from any answers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the `more` button, you can get the whole article exists in this css path `'.inline_editor_value > div > div'`

```
>>> c = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.inline_editor_value > div > div').text
>>> print len(c)
3491
>>> driver.find_element_by_class_name("more_link").click()
>>> c_new = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.inline_editor_value > div > div').text
>>> print len(c_new)
9642
```

Comment: i try to use this solution, but still not work.
He don't take text  content.

Comment: I did it successfully. Check shell output. Make your code simple than add try block.